# Regular Expression Using Ant

Tags: java, regex, ant

I am new to ant and I am trying the following :-

I have a file called `info.2013.tar.gz` .It is in a location memo.dir . I have to pass this file into a variable in ant and write a regular expression to get the year i.e. `2013` in an ant target .
I have been working on perl and I know how to do it using perl ,but I have no clue how to do that using ant.
Can anyone please help me .

```
<target name = "new" depends="load-props,classpath">
          <fileset dir = "${memo.dir}">
            <include name = "*.tar.gz"/>
          </fileset>
</target>
```

I tried something like this but it did not help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<pathconvert property="year">
    <mapper type="regexp" from="([^.]+)[.]tar[.]gz" to="\1"/>

    <path>
        <fileset dir="${memo.dir}">
            <include name="*.tar.gz"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
</pathconvert>

<echo>year: ${year}</echo>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the regex you have used?How do I get info from info.2013.tar.gz?

Answer (score 0):

You may use script task with builtin (since JDK 6) javascript engine, f.e. :

```
<project>
<!-- create macrodef for reuse -->
<macrodef name="splitstring">
  <attribute name="str" />
  <attribute name="by" />
  <attribute name="index" />
  <attribute name="result" />
  <sequential>
   <script language="javascript">
   // create property for further proccessing
   project.setProperty('@{result}', '@{str}'.split('@{by}')['@{index}']);
   </script>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

 <fileset dir = "${memo.dir}" id="whatever">
  <include name = "*.tar.gz"/>
 </fileset>

 <splitstring by="." str="${toString:whatever}" index="1" result="foobar" />

 <echo>$${foobar} => ${foobar}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${foobar} => 2013
```

Note that `project.setProperty()` may overwrite an existing property with the same name, otherwise use `project.setNewProperty()`, so :

```
<property name="foobar" value="value"/>

<splitstring by="." str="${toString:whatever}" index="1" result="foobar" />
```

would result in :

```
[echo] ${foobar} => value
```